# Paypal Suspend an agreement and Reactivate an agreement

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

If my billing cycle is 03-Dec-2014 to 03-Dec-2015 and so ,

Now i suspended the agreement for 3 month and Reactivating the agreement from 03-March-2015

so what will be my cycle it will start from the date when i reactivate

which is 03-March-2015 to 03-March-2016 or it will be in the same cycle

where i was started like from 03-Dec-2015 to 03-Dec-2016 and so

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The new date of subscription will start on the date you are reactivating the profile. Let say in this case you are reactivating the profile on 3rd March 2015, so the next cycle will be on the 3rd March 2016.